# What is wrong with my string queue struct?

Tags: c++, struct, queue

I can't get this to work properly, I'm trying to create a header file for a string queue that has functions for pop which returns and gets rid of the first value in the queue, push which inserts a value to the end, and isEmpty to check whether the queue is empty or not.

```
#ifndef Queue_h
#define Queue_h
#include <string>

struct Node {
    string data;
    Node* next;

    Node() {
        data = "";
        next = NULL;
    }

};

struct Queue {
    Node* first;
    Node* last;

    Queue() {
        first = NULL;
        last = NULL;
    }

    ~Queue() {
        Node* temp = first;

        while (temp != NULL) {
            temp = temp->next;
            delete first;
            first = temp;
        }
    }
    void push(string input) {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            Node* node = new Node();
            first = node;
            last = node;
            last->data = input;
        }
        else {
            Node* node2 = new Node();
            last->next = node2;
            last = last->next;
            last->data = input;
        }
    }

    string pop() {
        if (!isEmpty()) {
            string temp = first->data;
            Node* tpointer = first;
            first = first->next;
            delete tpointer;
            return temp;
        }
        return "";
    }

    bool isEmpty() {
        if (first == NULL) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
};

#endif
```

I'm getting a bunch of errors saying stuff like "data is not a member of Node" "data is an undeclared identifier" "data is an unknown override specifier". I would copy/paste my list of errors, but I don't know how to easily do that.

Edit: Now I am down to 4 errors after fixing my string declarations: pop is not a member of Queue line 17, pop unknown override specifier line 50, syntax error ( line 50, unexpected token preceding { line 50

Comment: 1. Make sure you use `#include <string>`. 2. Instead of `string data;`, use `std::string data;`.

Comment: Ok that got it down to 4 errors from like 16, I thought I didn't need to do that for some reason because when I hovered my mouse over string it was saying std::____ so I thought it already knew or something

Comment: Your header file is relying on you `using std::string` or something first. There's really just no reason to not write `std::string` when that's what you mean, as you will save yourself headaches in the long run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure you use `#include <string>`.
2. Instead of `string data;`, use `std::string data;`.
3. Use `std::string` instead of `string` at all other places too.

---

I posted the first two items above as a comment initially but I noticed a bug in the `pop()` function. I thought I would add them to this answer too.

You are not updating `last` correctly when popping the last item from a `Queue`.

```
std::string pop() {
    if (!isEmpty()) {
        std::string temp = first->data;
        Node* tpointer = first;
        if ( first == last )
        {
           first = last = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
           first = first->next;
        }
        delete tpointer;
        return temp;
    }
    return "";
}
```